# Shmget is returning a value of -1

Tags: c

When I run shmget in the following code it is returning a value of -1 and im not sure why that is the case. Everything else seems to be running fine. The code is just supposed to take in a few digits from the command line and then create shared memory for them. The digits will range from 0 to 9.

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int numArgc =(int)argc-1;    //number of vauled arguments passed
  int arrayId[numArgc];    
  pid_t pid;           
  int arrSpace[numArgc];       //array to store atoi of values
  int status;

  int *memory;         //pointer to shared memory
  int memoryId;        //check for smhget
  int childPID; 
  int childId;

  if(argc > 8 || argc < 2)     //check number of cmd line arg
  {
    printf("The number of arguments must be between 1 and 7");
    return(0);
  }
  else
  {
    for(int i=1; i<numArgc+1; i++)  //store args as integers
    {
      arrSpace[i]=atoi((argv[i]));
      printf("%d\n", arrSpace[i]);
    }
  }


  memoryId=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, try, IPC_CREAT | 07546); //create shared 
  printf("%d \n", memoryId);
  if(memoryId<0)
  {
    printf("There was an error with ID.\n");
    return (0);
  }
  printf("%s%d", "Size of shared Memory of parent is \n ", numArgc);

  memory=(int*)shmat(memoryId, NULL, 0);  // attaches shared memory
  if((long)memory == -1)
  {
    printf("There was an error running shmat  .\n");
    return (0);
  }

  printf("Share memory is now: \n");
  for(int i=0; i<numArgc; i++)
  {
    memory[i]=arrSpace[i];
  }
  printMemory(memory, numArgc);

  printf("Beginning fork process");
  for(childId; childId <= numArgc; childId++)
  {
    pid = fork(); //creates new process
    if(pid < 0)
    {
      printf("There was an error during fork process");
      return (0);
    }
    else if(pid == 0)
    {
      ChildProcess(memory, numArgc, childId);
      exit(0);
    }
  }

  ParentProcess(memory, childPID, numArgc, memoryId, status);
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: If a system call like `shmget` fails (i.e. returns `-1`) then you should check [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) for what went wrong. Use e.g. [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) to get a nice printable string of the error. Also of course consult [the `shmget` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html) for details.

Comment: `try` variable does not seem defined.

Comment: this line: `for(childId; childId <= numArgc; childId++)` is nonsense for two reasons. 1) the syntax for the first parameter is not valid.  2) the variable `childId` is not initialized, so contains garbage (what ever was in memory wher the variable is located on the stacl

Comment: Never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter actually exists.

Comment: regarding these two lines: `printf("The number of arguments must be between 1 and 7");  return(0);`   1) a return value of 0 indicates success, but the operation actually failed, suggest: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE )l`  Note: both `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are found in stdlib.h  2) error messages should be output to stderr, not stdout. AND when outputting an error message about the command line parameter list, the message should be a USAGE statement,  I.E. indicate optional parmeters and the meaning of each parameter.

Comment: this line: `for(int i=1; i<numArgc+1; i++)` will access the `argv[]` one past any valid command line parameters (I.E. the final NULL parameter)  Amongst other problems, dereferencing NULL is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.   Note: in C, array offsets start with 0 and continue to `num array entries -1`

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: How are we expected to test/debug your code.  there are 3 functions being called that are not defined, not even a prototype.  Those functions are: `printMemory()`  `ChildProcess()` and `ParentProcess()`

Comment: the checking for an error from one of the calls to `fork()` should NOT just `return`.  Rather it should call `wait()` or better `waitpid() for each of the child processes that was successfully created.  otherwise, when the parent exits, the child processes become `zombies`  `zombies` are very difficult to eliminate without rebooting the computer.  For best results, strongly suggest keeping each `pid` returned from `fork()` in an array, so they are available when recovering from any error.

Comment: regarding these two lines: `memory=(int*)shmat(memoryId, NULL, 0);  // attaches shared memory
  if((long)memory == -1)`  `shmat()` returns a `void*`.  this is being cast to a `int*`  then the second line is re-casting it to a `long int`.  The code needs to be consistent.   Also, the correct cast is `(void*)-1`.   When an error indication is returned, the reason the system thinks the error occurred needs to be displayed.  Strongly suggest a statement similar to: `perror( "shmat failed" );` as that will 1) output to stderr and 2) include the system error message,

Comment: when calling `shmget()` and a -1 is returned, call `perror()` similar to: `perror( "shmget failed" );`  which will properly output the message to stderr and will also output the error message from the system that shows what the system thinks was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shmget returns -1 because try variable is undefined and the permission 07546 is invalid.Please pass appropriate permission for the memory segment.

```
#define MEMORY_SIZE 20 //size of memory segment
memoryId=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, MEMORY_SIZE , IPC_CREAT | 0666); //create shared 
printf("%d \n", memoryId);
```

Comment: it is still passing -1

Comment: that `7` in the answer is enabling `execute` permission for the current user.  Is that what you actually want.  Typical permission would be `0666` which would be read+write permissions for everyone.